# how to mock EventSource using jest with TS (tried most of the mocking strategy)

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

wanted to mock EventSource using jest, but kept throwing `ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined`.

Please have a look at the code. Thanks a lot!

```
// eventSourceHandler.ts
export default new class A() {
listenEventSource(){
    const eventSource = new EventSource(url);
    eventSource.addEventListener("something", callSomething);
    eventSource.onerror = function() {
      console.error();
      ("Failed to listen EventSource");
    };
}
}
```

Here is test code I want to mock

```
// eventSourceHandler.spec.ts

import A from "./eventSourceHandler"
describe("xyz",() =>{
it("eventSourceHandler called", ()=> {
const mEventSourceInstance = {
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        onerror: jest.fn(),
        close: jest.fn(),
        onmessage: jest.fn(),
        onopen: jest.fn(),
        url: "test-url",
        readyState: 0,
        withCredentials: false,
        CLOSED: 2,
        CONNECTING: 0,
        OPEN: 1,
        removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
        dispatchEvent: jest.fn()
      };
      jest.mock("EventSource", () => {
        return {
          EventSource: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
              // addEventListener: jest.fn(),
              // onerror: jest.fn()
              mEventSourceInstance
            };
          })
        };
      });
      let a = new A()
      a.listenEventSource();
      // test validation ....
});
});
});
...
```

Kept getting `ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined` whenever run test code.

**NOTE:** I've read almost most related posts from stackoverflow and tried to mock `global.EventSource` but Typescript kept throwing error saying `EventSource does not exist on type Global`.

Is there anyone who wants to share a better mocking strategy for this?
That will be highly appreciated.

Thanks guyzz ...

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/gcedo/eventsourcemock

Answer (score 3):

Well, I see two alternatives you might use.

- Inject the eventSource instance in the class it's being used, so you can mock it
- Use a builder function instead of calling the constructor directly in class A

For the latter, you could end up with something like this:

*utils.ts*

```
export const buildEventSource = (url: string) => {
  return new EventSource(url, {});
};
```

And then in your test class:

```
import * as utils from './utils';

const buildEventSourceSpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'buildEventSource');

buildEventSourceSpy.mockReturnValue({
    CLOSED: 0,
    CONNECTING: 0,
    OPEN: 0,
    dispatchEvent(event: Event): boolean {
      return false;
    },
    onerror: jest.fn(),
    onmessage: jest.fn(),
    onopen: jest.fn(),
    readyState: 0,
    url: '',
    withCredentials: false,
    addEventListener(
      type: any,
      listener: any,
      options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions
    ): void {},
    close(): void {},
    removeEventListener(
      type: any,
      listener: any,
      options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions
    ): void {}
  });
```

I hope it helps

Comment: how could we test the `onMessage` handler with this setup?

Answer (score 2):

It was struggling with `ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined for a while.
But turns out official jest [doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports) has pretty good explanation of what is up.

It's just that global objects are hoisted as soon as your import your piece of code that uses it and then can not be changed (kind of like a closure in my understanding).

So an easy work-around is to keep your definition of mocked global variables like `EventSource` in a separate module and import it before any other module that uses globals.

For instantce I have a module `mockEventSource.ts` with a following contents

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'EventSource', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    close: jest.fn(() => {}),
    addEventListener: jest.fn(
      (_event: string, _callback: (_message: MessageEvent) => {}) => {},
    ),
  })),
});
```

Then in my test file I do:

```
import './mockEventSource.ts';
import { myFunction } from './moduleToTest.ts';
```

And now when I call `myFunction` it should have an access to mocked `EventSource`

Answer (score 1):

As @amir-raminfar suggests, [`eventsourcemock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventsourcemock) should do the trick. After `npm install eventsourcemock`, I added the following to my jest setup tests file (I was using create-react-app, so it was just ./setupTests.js for me:

```
import EventSource from 'eventsourcemock';

Object.defineProperty(window, 'EventSource', {
    value: EventSource,
});
```

Then, in the test, you would have something like

```
import {sources} from 'eventsourcemock';

const messageEvent = new MessageEvent('something', {
  data: '1',
});

sources[url].emit(
      messageEvent.type,
      messageEvent
    );
    expect(... your expected behaviour here);
```

The `sources[url]` will return a direct reference to the implementation the application code is using, so there's various things you can manipulate and inspect. In my tests, I couldn't get my `onmessage` listener to fire with `emit`, but if I called `sources[url].onmessage` directly with my test payload, that worked well.